# How can I get x,y Position in parent view controller Objective c

Tags: objective-c

I a have UIView1 that hold a child `UIView2`,`UIView2` hold a child `UILabel`.

Is it possible to get x,y of that `UILabel` depending on`UIView1`.

I tried to work with `convertPoint` without success.

Comment: A view controller does not have a location. Likely you meant parent view. However, which code did not work for you?

Comment: Please, add a code citation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out!

```
CGRect NewFrame = [View1 convertRect:YourLabel.frame fromView:View2];
```

check your NewFrame according to first view.

```
CGFloat Xposition = NewFrame.frame.origin.x; 
CGFloat Yposition = NewFrame.frame.origin.y;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400)];
UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
[view1 addSubview:view2];
[view2 addSubview:label];


CGRect rect = [label.superview convertRect:label.frame toView:view1];
```